# Multi-Dimensional Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am working in Java and am wondering, are multi-dimensional arrays like grids where rows are elements and columns are dimensions, or are they hyper-geometric figures that we can't see?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A 1D array is like a list, a 2D array is like a table with columns and rows, a 3D array is like a cube, x, y and z and anything more than that would be hyper-geometric.  You could represent a cube with time with a 4D array.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it's useful to think of multidimensional arrays as geometric: lists, tables, cubes.  Other times, such as when the arrays aren't of equal length, it's not.  They might be:

- lists of tables
- lists of lists of lists
- tables of cubes

At some (early) point it's time to make some `class`es.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how many dimensions you create the array with. Obviously you can create a 2 dimensional array that is a table.